# How to change the schema of a pyspark dataframe that has an array of floats?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, schema

I have a spark dataframe that initially has this format.

```
+------+-----+--------+
|id    |v1   |v2      |
+------+-----+--------+
|1000|  0.5  | -5.0   |
|1001|  0.3, | -8.1   |
|1002|  2.2, | -7.0   |
```

Then I convert to this format, because an algorithm requires this format.

```
+------+------------+
|id    |values       |
+------+------------+
|1000| [0.5,-5.0]   |
|1001| [0.3,-8.1]   |
|1002| [2.2,-7.0]   |
```

This spark dataframe has the following schema.

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- value: vector (nullable = true)
```

But the algorithm requires this schema:

```
schema = StructType([StructField("id", IntegerType(), False), StructField("values", ArrayType(FloatType()), False)])
```

But I can't change the schema. Does anyone know how to solve this in pyspark?

Comment: Just to understand a bit better, you want your `value` to be `ArrayType` right? Not `vector`?

Comment: The final dataframe needs to have this format:

df_finish.printSchema()
root
  |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
  |-- value: array (nullable = false)
        |-- element: float (containsNull = true)

Comment: This schema was suggested by the author of the algorithm I will use. But I can't apply it without errors.

schema = StructType([StructField("id", IntegerType(), False), StructField("values", ArrayType(FloatType()), False)])

Comment: T.ArrayType with elements of type T.FloatType()

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`vector_to_array`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.functions.vector_to_array.html):

```py
from pyspark.ml.functions import vector_to_array

df_array = df.withColumn('values', vector_to_array("values", "float32"))
```

I'm assuming that your input `DataFrame` is something like this:

```py
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1000, Vectors.dense(.5, -5.)),
        (1001, Vectors.dense(.3, 8.1)),
        (1002, Vectors.dense(2.2, 7.)),
        (1003, Vectors.sparse(3, [(0, 2.0), (2, 3.0)]))
    ],
    ["id", "values"]
)


+----+-------------------+
|  id|             values|
+----+-------------------+
|1000|         [0.5,-5.0]|
|1001|          [0.3,8.1]|
|1002|          [2.2,7.0]|
|1003|(3,[0,2],[2.0,3.0])|
+----+-------------------+

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- values: vector (nullable = true)
```

Than `df_array` will be:

```py
+----+---------------+
|  id|         values|
+----+---------------+
|1000|    [0.5, -5.0]|
|1001|     [0.3, 8.1]|
|1002|     [2.2, 7.0]|
|1003|[2.0, 0.0, 3.0]|
+----+---------------+

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- values: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: float (containsNull = false)
```